# Why can't I see bot navigation mesh in TF2?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I have turned on `sv_cheats 1` and run `nav_generate` on the server. Then I set `nav_edit 1` from within TF2 (client-side), but no mesh appears. I've added bots, and they clearly follow the generated nav, so it *does* exist, I just can't see it.

I've followed [this tutorial](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Navigation_Meshes) and looked at various guides and forum posts, but no luck.

I've tried turning on `nav_edit 1` on the server side instead, but it starts an infinite loop of error messages saying:

```
UTIL_getlistenserverhost() called from a dedicated server or single-player game
```

I've tried different maps and different map types, no difference.

I've tried two different computers, no difference.

What am I missing or doing wrong? Is there a graphics setting I need to change, maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Instead of connecting to a remote server (even one that happens to be on the same machine or accessible over LAN), I needed to start a server from within TF2 client.

When I did it that way, nav meshes showed up and were editable as per the linked tutorial.